# авто выдача роли и приветствие Discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Написал код. должен писать приветствие и выдавать роль. так же сделал пометки мне в батнике пишет действия которые написаны в принте. и при выполнение действия выдачи роли должно, мне не роль не выдаёт и не пишет

````
@client.event

async def on_ready():
    print ('bot connected')

#авто выдача роли

@client.event

async def on_member_join (member):
    channel = client.get_channel ( 839807318162145290 )

    role = discord.utils.get (member.guild.roles, id=839807022949335050)
    print ('user join the servers')
    await member.add_roles( role )
    await channel.send( embed = discord.Embed( description = f'``{member.name}`` присоиединился', color = 0x0c0c0c))```
````

Comment: Возможно у бота нет права "Управление ролями" или его роль в списке ролей находится ниже то, которую он должен выдать?

Comment: нет. тут всё хорошо. всё норм. Тут проблема в другом, а в чём? я не знаю

Comment: попробуйте получить роль таким способом: roleAdd = get(guild.roles, name="НАЗВАНИЕ"). Если что, потом на ид смените

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код написан правильно, но не работает из-за того, что вы не выдали боту намерения (intents).

Чтобы их выдать, вам нужно при инициализации бота, помимо префикса указать также намерения.

**1. Указываем необходимые намерения** *(В данном случае все)*:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
```

**2. Выдаем их боту:**

```
# Если у вас discord.Client
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

# Если у вас commands.Bot
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

Затем включите два пункта на странице вашего бота. Для этого зайдите в [раздел приложений](https://discord.com/developers/applications) и выберите вашего бота. Затем, слева, на вкладке "Bot"

[image: Бот]

Включите параметры `PRESENCE INTENT` и `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После этого `on_member_join()` заработает.

Comment: не помогло((( правильно я ввёл?

PREFIX = '.'
intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.', intents=intents)

что означает "Если у вас discord.Client" и "Если у вас commands.Bot"

Comment: У вас бот это discord.Client() или discord.ext.commands.Bot()? В зависимости от этого и добавляйте намерения в вашего бота, пример я написал в ответе