# не выводит сообщение при входе на сервер

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

когда кто то заходит мне ничего не пишет. в Discord Developer Portal я уже всё включил, если можете напиши что надо сделать в коде)

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join (member):

    print ('user connected')
```

Comment: Намерения `discord.intents` выданы?

Comment: Я уже отвечал на подобный вопрос, посмотрите еще раз, пожалуйста [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1278781/%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5-discord-py/1279204#1279204)