# Как сделать автовыдачу роли и приветсвтвие

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Всем прив, я не особо разбираюсь в питоне поэтому спрашиваю, как написать код, чтобы он писал в канал с id 947591418199822356 приветствие нового участника и выдал ему роль с id 935467923143790602 ? заранее спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: он норм сделан.

Comment: Подобные вопросы допустимы в качестве только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу. На stackoverflow не принято писать готовые решения

Comment: @denisnumb
я просто не знаю как делать

Comment: Тогда изучите необходимый материал, все не так сложно. Можете почитать [**руководство по работе с библиотекой**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md), попытаться написать код и если что-то не будет получаться, то уже писать сюда. На этот вопрос вам на вряд ли дадут ответ, потому что это не вопрос, а запрос на готовый код

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [авто выдача роли и приветствие Discord.py](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1278781/%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b5-discord-py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого нужно использовать ивент on_message. Пример кода как такое можно реализовать:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(947591418199822356)
    await cahnnel.send(f"На сервере новый участник {member.mention}")
    role = member.guild.get_role(935467923143790602)
    await member.add_roles(role)
```

Этот код будет писать в канал с id 947591418199822356 о том что появился новый участник на сервере, а также он будет выдавать роль с id 935467923143790602

Comment: спасибо вам огромное!!!

Comment: только небольшая проблемка, при заходе участника не пишется в канале с айди  947591418199822356 и не выдает роль с айди 935467923143790602